# a mysql request, nothing happen?

Tags: php, mysql

in PHP; a got this mysql request:

```
$q=@mysql_query("INSERT INTO personnes(login,pass,user_email,logged_ip,created,user_first_name,user_last_name,user_organization,user_address1,user_address2,user_city, 
            user_country,user_zip,user_phone,userer_fax) VALUES ('".mysql_escape_real_string($login)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($pass)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($user_mail)."', 
            '".mysql_escape_real_string($ip)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string( $dates)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($first_name)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($last_name)."', 
            '".mysql_escape_real_string($organisation)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($address1)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($address2)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($city)."', 
            '".mysql_escape_real_string('France')."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($zip)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($phone)."', '".mysql_escape_real_string($fax)."')");
```

Well; I use to got some troubles with this request, because of types ..etc; but when I finally have no error; nothing happens.
I put an ECHO after the request, but it is never reached
Thank you

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in 5.6 and removed in 7!!

Comment: Deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. @Daan

Comment: 'code'$q=@mysql_query("SELECT login, pass FROM pmd_users");
This request works !!!

Comment: You have no errors because using `@` suppresses all errors.

Comment: and don't use @ it will hide errors (which you want to see to figure out what's going wrong)

Comment: There are errors. The function `mysql_escape_real_string` does not exist. The function is called `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: In general, only suppress errors if you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois In general, never ever suppress errors, but handle them properly.

Comment: @Oldskool I had to use the stfu operator in some cases, thus there is no never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Should be

```
$q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO personnes(login,pass,user_email,logged_ip,created,user_first_name,user_last_name,user_organization,user_address1,user_address2,user_city, 
            user_country,user_zip,user_phone,userer_fax) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($login)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_mail)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($ip)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string( $dates)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($organisation)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($address1)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($address2)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string('France')."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($zip)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($phone)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($fax)."')");
```

Note : mysql_* functions are deprecated in 5.6 and removed in 7!!

Deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've written the function mysql_escape_real_string incorrectly.

It's [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

And it's not a good practice to use @ during development phase. You could add debugging codes like:

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... " );

if (!$q) {
   die(mysql_error()); // You'll be notified if there's any syntax error in your query.
}
```